# How can the font size in empathy be configured?

Tags: 10.04, gnome, fonts, empathy

Empathy uses a very small font size. I'd like to have some larger font. But the system setting has no entry for fonts. How can I use another/larger font in empathy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug has been reported. However, if you are using the adium theme there is a workaround [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/empathy/+bug/504771/comments/9).